# Can the Laplace transform be inverted?

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

Consider the Laplace transform $\tilde{f}(s)$ of a function $f(t)$ defined as $$\tilde{f}(s)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st} \, dt.$$ Can this relation be inverted to obtain $f(t)$ in terms of $\tilde{f}(s)$?

The reason I ask this is as follows. The Fourier transform $$\tilde{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ikx} \, dx$$ is defined simulataneously with the inversion formula $$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\tilde{f}(k)e^{ikx} \, dk.$$ But I haven't seen the same for the Laplace's transform.

Comment: Well yes. Put it this way, if $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Laplace transform and you know $\mathcal{L}(f) = \tilde f$, then $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\tilde f) = f(t)$.

Comment: @Shaun : This does not look at all like the sorts of homework exercises for which remarks like yours are appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Laplace transform can be inverted. Based on your earlier  question I suspect you're actually curious whether the inverse is given by $$f(t)=\int_0^\infty\tilde f(s)e^{-st}\,ds.$$No, that is absolutely not how you invert the Laplace transform.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly is my confusion. What's the inversion formula then? And how is it derived?

Comment: The story is not nearly as simple as for the Fourier transform. See the other answer...

Answer (score 2):

If $\widetilde{f}$ converges on $\gamma+i\mathbb{R}$ with $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$, the inverse can be obtained as $$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\widetilde{f}(s)e^{st}ds.$$An alternative expression for the inverse Laplace transform is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_inversion_formula).

Comment: Is that actually true without any additional hypotheses, like regarding integrability?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Good question, but I'm not an expert. For the formula I included in the answer, it suffices for $f$ to be a tempered analytic function; for the formula I linked to, we assume also a weak-$\ast$ topology. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Inverse_Laplace_transform).

Comment: Yeah, I scribbled a little and I sort of believe it. "For almost every $t$',  of course...